# add new column in R based on condition from another column

Tags: r, dataframe, variables

I have a data.frame like this:

```
Clinic    Month         Appointments
A         31-01-2019    0
A         28-02-2019    0
A         31-03-2019    3
A         30-04-2019    5
A         31-05-2019    0
A         30-06-2019    5 
B         31-01-2019    0
B         28-02-2019    5
```

And I would like to add a new column called `Live_months` with the number of months since the first appointment, even if there is another month with 0 appointments afterwards, such as:

```
Clinic    Month         Appointments      Live_months
A         31-01-2019    0                 0
A         28-02-2019    0                 0
A         31-03-2019    3                 1
A         30-04-2019    5                 2
A         31-05-2019    0                 3
A         30-06-2019    5                 4
B         31-01-2019    0                 0
B         28-02-2019    5                 1
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Clinic) %>% mutate(Month = lubridate::dmy(Month)) %>% filter(row_number() >= min(month(Month)[Appointments != 0])) %>% 
  mutate(Live_months = row_number()) %>% right_join(df %>% mutate(Month = lubridate::dmy(Month)), by = c('Clinic','Month')) %>% 
  mutate(Live_months = replace_na(Live_months, 0)) %>% 
  select(Clinic, Month, 'Appointments' = Appointments.y, Live_months) %>% arrange(Clinic, Month)
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   Clinic [2]
  Clinic Month      Appointments Live_months
  <chr>  <date>            <dbl>       <dbl>
1 A      2019-01-31            0           0
2 A      2019-02-28            0           0
3 A      2019-03-31            3           1
4 A      2019-04-30            5           2
5 A      2019-05-31            0           3
6 A      2019-06-30            5           4
7 B      2019-01-31            0           0
8 B      2019-02-28            5           1
```

Comment: Thanks v much Karthik for your suggestion but your solutions sets Live_months to 1 on 28-02-2019 for Clinic A, and it should be 0, only on 31-03-2019 there were the first 3 appointments. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues, yeah I had this doubt, but when you look at Clinic B, shouldn't 28-02-2019 also be 0?

Comment: Thanks Karthik. Different clinics go live at different times. Clinic B started appointments on 28-02-2019 so the clinic went live on that month, so we will have Live_months = 1 on that month. Does it make sense?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues, have made the changes, can you please check now.

Comment: Thanks Karthik but after running your code, I get the following error message: Error in select(., Clinic, Month, Appointments = Appointments.y) : 
  unused arguments (Clinic, Month, Appointments = Appointments.y)

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues, did you use quotes for Appointments as in my answer? You need to use 'Appointments' = Appointments.y

Comment: Yes I did. I put 'Appointments' = Appointments.y in the code, but the error message does not print it with ' '

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy(Month),
         year = year(Date), 
         Month = month(Date)) %>%
  arrange(Clinic, Date) %>%
  group_by(Clinic) %>%
  mutate(Live_months = {
    i <- which(Appointments > 0)[1]
    pmax((year - year[i]) * 12 + Month - Month[i] + 1, 0)
  })

#  Clinic Month Appointments Date        year Live_months
#  <chr>  <dbl>        <int> <date>     <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 A          1            0 2019-01-31  2019           0
#2 A          2            0 2019-02-28  2019           0
#3 A          3            3 2019-03-31  2019           1
#4 A          4            5 2019-04-30  2019           2
#5 A          5            0 2019-05-31  2019           3
#6 A          6            5 2019-06-30  2019           4
#7 B          1            0 2019-01-31  2019           0
#8 B          2            5 2019-02-28  2019           1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Clinic = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B"), Month = c("31-01-2019", "28-02-2019", "31-03-2019", "30-04-2019", 
"31-05-2019", "30-06-2019", "31-01-2019", "28-02-2019"), Appointments = c(0L, 
0L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak for your suggestion but not all months have 30 days, some have 28 days, others 31 days. So I am afraid your proposed solution does not work in my case.

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues If the first appointment date is 15th February when does 2nd Live month start?

Comment: Thanks Ronak. The variable Month includes the last day of the month. So for clinic A, the first appointments started in March 2019 but that does not mean it was on the last day. the number of appointments is per month. I could use the first day of the month, but I decided to use the last to categorise the month. Does it make sense?

Comment: If the first appointment is 15th February 2019, it will be associated to Month = 2019-02-28 so Live_months = 1 for 2019-02-28.

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues I think the updated answer should help. Can you try that?

Comment: Thanks Ronak. I tried that, but didn't work. I only get a my 3 current columns + 'Date' column with NAs and Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `Date`.
ℹ All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
ℹ Input `Date` is `dmy(Month)`. 
2: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Month is in Date format already. Any ideas of why this is happening?

Comment: I can debug further if you share your data using `dput`. Maybe your data has a different structure.

Comment: Thanks Ronak but I found another way to do it - appreciate your time.